# Array modifier makes wrong offset - rotation (it has parent)

Tags: modeling, modifiers

i made apply transforms on the object and parent has 0 0 0 position

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Reposition the 3d cursor (center) using the 3d cursor tool. Also press SHIFT+S, and select "Cursor to world origin".

Comment: its not working, array modifier is not using the 3D cursor (NEVER)